# как сделать upgrade только некоторых таблиц в SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public class DataSource extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

 @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DB_CREATE_CATEGORY);
    db.execSQL(DB_CREATE_PRODUCT);
    db.execSQL(DB_CREATE_BRAND);
    db.execSQL((DB_CREATE_ORDER));
    db.execSQL((DB_CREATE_ORDER_POSITION));
    db.execSQL(DB_CREATE_GALLERY);

}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CATEGORY);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCT);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_BRAND);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ORDER);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ORDER_POSITIONS);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_GALLERY);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

Так же есть сервис который заполняет БД, один метод заполняет полностью  все таблицы, а второй только `TABLE_ORDER` и `TABLE_ORDER_POSITIONS`. И в случае если первый метод уже заполнил все таблицы, а потом вызывается второй метод который заполняет `TABLE_ORDER` и `TABLE_ORDER_POSITIONS` - то данные в этих  таблицах дублируются.

ВОПРОС: как можно сделать `upgrade` этих таблиц, не затрагивая остальные.

Comment: Не делайте запросов к другим таблицам просто. Вы же удаляете все, и тупо создаете заново.

Comment: Да, но как это сделать, если мне нужно что бы можно было уронить все таблицы и создать их заново и отдельно сделать тоже самое но только с таблицами TABLE_ORDER и TABLE_ORDER_POSITIONS

Comment: делайте все в зависимости от версии. `if(oldVersion == 10 && newVersion == 15) { //пересоздать только одну таблицу}`

Comment: Можно немножко подробней, я так понимаю это к моделям надо еще добавить поле version ? Как отслеживать эти версии? Можно какой-то пример реализации?

Comment: вам в параметры метода `onUpgrade` приходят `SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion`

Comment: if(oldVersion == 10 && newVersion == 15) { //пересоздать только одну         таблицу}
да но в какой то момент диапазоны версий для удаления всех таблиц и удаления только двух могут пересечься? Или я неправильно понимаю механизм этих версий?

Comment: Это вы должны знать. У вас же есть четкий критерий, в какой ситуации надо удалять, а в како - не надо? Вот и спроецируйте его на версии базы.

Comment: Если радикально подходить, то напишите по методу для обновления с версии N до N+1, и последовательно вызывайте.

Comment: @metalurgus допустим с версиями я разберусь, а как быть c onCreate, там то у меня создаются все таблицы, и возникает ошибка?

Comment: @zRrr не понял, можно подробней?

Comment: значит создавайте не все таблицы, это же очевидно!

Comment: @metalurgus разумеется, не понятно только как в методе onCreate понять какие таблицы были удалены и какие нужно заново создать, потому что в onCreate передается только один аргумент. В голову пришло только создавать таблицы заново прям в методе onUpgrade, если есть идеи как это можно  сделать в onCreate - было бы неплохо!

Comment: А вы не используйте `onCreate`. Вас никто не заставляет.

Comment: @metalurgus и у меня еще один вопрос, могу ли я постоянно передавать одни и те же версии? На пример:
- dataSource.onUpgrade(dataSource.getWritableDatabase(), 1, 2); - для удаления всех таблиц 
- dataSource.onUpgrade(dataSource.getWritableDatabase(), 3, 4); - для удаления только  двух? 
Ну а в методе onUpgrade соответственно стоят If() для первого и второго варианта, я попробовал - вроде работает, но не уверен что это правильный подход!